# How to get database field values from extbase action?

Tags: database, repository, action, typo3, extbase

now that I managed to get random AJAX output, I want to get some useful values from the database as the next step.

Once again, my AJAX call looks like this (additionally, I added a JSON call, which would be even better).

```
        
        $.ajax({
              url: "index.php",
              data: "tx_myext_myplugin1[controller]=Mycontroller1&tx_myext_myplugin1[action]=ajax&type=89657201",
              success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
              }
            });

    /*
    var uri = '<f:uri.action action="ajax" controller="Mycontroller1" pageType="89657201" />';

    jQuery.getJSON(uri, function(result) {
        alert(result.c);
    });
    */
```

my ajaxAction function:

```
        
        public function ajaxAction() {
        $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

        return json_encode($arr);
    }
```

This works when I use the JSON call, now I need to get an array with database values though. I thought calling the repository with a findAll() function would already help, but it's not an array I think, which is why I can't use it. A different idea would be to use the getValue methods I wrote in the Model, but I'm not sure if this would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Disclaimer:*** *Generally using findAll() method can be real `performance killer` therefore try to write custom finders, selecting only required properties, especcialy if your model is big or contains many relations!*

You are close enough, as you can send findAll() result with json_encode(), but  be careful, depending on your model, json created from findAll can be really huge. It's better idea to iterate results and rewrite to new array only required values.

```
    $dataFromRepo = $this->yourRepository->findAll();

    $resultArray = array();

    foreach ($dataFromRepo as $object){
        $resultArray[$object->getUid()] = $object->getTitle();
    }

    return json_encode($resultArray);
```

in result you'll get basic JSON `object`:

```
{
    "1": "Title of first item",
    "2": "Second item",
    "3": "Et cetera"
}
```

When you'll remove custom index from `$resultArray`

```
    foreach ($dataFromRepo as $object){
        $resultArray[] = $object->getTitle();
    }
```

you will get JSON `array`

```
[
    "Title of first item",
    "Second item",
    "Et cetera"
]
```

And so on. Of course you can also build this way `multidimensional array` and send more sophisticated objects to get all you need at once.

P.S. Try always to use for an example [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) - online validator to validate if the output you're expecting is valid.

Comment: You can iterate through `$dataFromRepo` without calling `toArray()` on the `QueryResults` object, btw.

Comment: @peter: You're right of course. In this case toArray() is redundant call.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm, only one problem for me left, I'll ask that in the next, hopefully last question :)